# merging on 2 data frames using R for specified columns

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 files and I want to merge them into one based on 3 columns.
File 1 looks like this

```
chr1    10  15  256 123
chr2    20  40  12  1
```

FIle 2 looks like this

```
chr1    10  15  100 90
chr2    20  40  17  23
```

My files are not having headers. I want to combine the 2 files on first 3 columns(coordinates in 2 files are same) and output the result something like this

```
chr1    10  15  256 100 
chr2    20  40  12  17
```

So basically first 3 columns are constant and 4th and 5th columns are basically the 4th column of the respective files.

How can I do this in R?

I tried this

```
file1 <- read.table('rtestfile1.txt', sep="\t",header=F)
file2 <- read.table('rtestfile2.txt', sep="\t",header=F)
total <- merge(file1,file2,by=c(V1,V2,V3))
```

It gave me an error saying:

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : object 'V1' not found

Comment: add quotes to "V1", "V2", "V3"

Comment: ADDING QUOTES WORKED BUT CAN I just select only the 4th column from the 2 files to be outputted?

Comment: do you mean `total[,4]`? I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: In the output file I want first 3 columns which are same in both the files but then the fourth column in the output file should be fourth column of the file1 and fifth column in the output file should be fourth column of the file2. Have a look at the output

Comment: I don't see any data.frames with 5 columns, maybe I am missing something

Comment: Can you see 5 columns in my question?

Comment: my mistake I was reading those as rownames

Comment: The output merges all the columns after first three columns, I want to output 4th column from respective files. Is that possible with merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `total <- merge(file1[, 1:4], file2[, 1:4], by = c("V1", "V2", "V3"))`

Use the `[, 1:3]` because the fourth column of each file is not desired. The `by` argument is the names of columns that are the same across files that you want to merge on.

Comment: Doesn't output what i want

Comment: It was unclear that chr1 and chr2 were there own clumns and not row names. Try again now.